# Unable to telnet to SQL mirroring port on public IP on Azure ARM VM

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-machine, database-mirroring

I am trying to mirror a on premise SQL database to Azure ARM VMs running SQL server. One for the mirror and one for the witness. I have setup the mirroring end points on the servers. However, I am getting an error to the effect that the mirror server can not be reached.

Reading through the net pages, I tested the port using telnet. I am able to telnet to the mirroring port on my local server from the Azure VM but unable to telnet from the local server to the VMs.

I am able to telnet on the mirroring port between the VMs using the Private IP Address but unable to do so using the Public IP address.

I have added the port to the Security group being used by these VMs to allow inbound connections as well as outbound connections.

I have tested that the server is listening on ip 0.0.0.0 and my mirroring port.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever its worth, I was setting the Inbound connections source port range as the port I was going to use for mirroring. I changed this to "*" and it started working.